# How to close an Activity, not the whole app

Tags: android

I'd like to destroy an Activity when the user clicks on a button (not the back button, a different button). I've decided to just call `super.onBackPressed`. Is that okay? What's a better way to close the current Activity without closing the whole app?

Comment: Just call finish(). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()

Comment: finish() method closes your current activity.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why my question was downvoted. If the answer is so obvious, I guess I'm not good at searching for my question because all of the solutions I found were for closing an Activity and the entire app.

Comment: just perform the finish(); function within that activity. I suggest you check out http://youtu.be/P4PqZKmQjjs this video Learn Android Tutorial 1.8 on a splash activity. It helped me understand how it worked better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Closing Activity Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134231/android-closing-activity-programmatically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for closing an Activity you can use finish() , but you have to aware of back stack, if you finish your last activity in the stack so there will be no activity in your stack and you must restart your app .

see more information on : [Task and BackStack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation of super.onBackPressed finishes the activity.
Instead of using super.onBackPressed , Better way to close the current activity will be to call finish() method.

Answer (score -1):

Also, When you press the back button, the onResume method is called.
Use onResume Method and refresh your stuff there.

Also, if it is listView refresh the data -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/12662994/2006412